# Opposite of verb "abstract" and noun "abstraction"

Tags: antonyms

The opposite of *abstract* (adj) is *concrete*, but what are the opposites of other forms of the word *abstract*, such as:

- *abstract* (v) - E.g.: We can abstract away the implementation details.
- *abstraction* (n) - E.g.: I will provide an abstraction to simplify this.

I'm interested in this from a computer science perspective. Abstraction is an important concept and I often find myself needing the opposite when explaining/modeling something. I'm currently using *implement* and *implementation*, but I feel this isn't quite correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[American Heritage](http://www.wordnik.com/words/concretize)* has *concretize*, but *specify* came to my mind.

> **concretize** To make real or specific.
>
> **specify** To state explicitly or in detail.

Comment: Any thoughts on what the "concretize" form of "abstraction" would be... concretization I suppose?

Comment: @chaiguy: _[Concretization](http://www.wordnik.com/words/concretization)_: Scrabble score—27, Mouthfeel score—0.

Answer (score 9):

You may also consider **TO REIFY** and **REIFICATION**.
Broadly speaking it means "to make real". (See http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reify).

Reification has a specific meaning in computer science as "the process by which an abstract idea about a computer program is turned into an explicit data model or other object" (quoting Wikipedia).
You may wish to read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Fascinating! Wasn't aware of that one at all... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Strictly in the Computer Science realm, we use "concrete" as the opposite of "abstract" as adjectives.  You cannot instantiate (make one of) an abstract class; you can instantiate a concrete class.  So "instantiation" probably comes close to the noun, and "instantiate" comes close to the verb.  Purely in terms of taxonomy, you could use "generalization/generalize" when going up a class heirarchy towards the more abstract ("vehicle" is a generalization of "car") and "specialization/specialize" going the other way.

Answer (score 1):

**Implement** may be a good choice:

> We can implement the details.

Another choice is **flesh out**:

> We can flesh out the implementation details.

Or you can use both:

> I will provide an implementation to flesh this out.

**Fill out** can also work instead of flesh out.  As well, the verb form of **detail** can be used:

> I will provide an implementation to detail this.

Comment: This is what I'm currently using; good to know it at least makes sense to someone else. :)

Comment: The term "expand" is used in mathematics. For instance "The Taylor Expansion". "Decompression" too. Abstraction can be thought of as a form of compression. See Juergen Schmidhuber's papers.